# Classical solution of fractional laplacian

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

What is meant by a classical solution of a fractional laplacian in $ (-\Delta)^su= f(u)$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ with no condition at infinity? If one can show that $u$ is a weak solution of the above solution, how does one show it is classical.?

Comment: I would guess that "classical" means "pointwise"; I am not sure what would "no condition at infinity" mean. Can you provide a broader context?

Comment: I thought any bounded weak solution is a classical solution (smooth in space and time)

Comment: By "no condition at infinity", the solution may be bounded or does not decay at infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Usually authors define a classical solutions as a continuous function which satisfies your equation in the pointwise sense i.e for every $x$. Conditions at infinity often motivate the proof technique used to show existence of solutions, for instance if $f$ is sublinear at infinity i.e is dominated by a line, sub- and supersolution method may work. If $f$ is superlinear at infinity, i.e dominates a line, then the sub- and supersolution method likely fails and some other degree theoretic or variational approach can show existence.